# C# Send Email with embedded images using CDOSYS

Tags: c#, email, html-agility-pack, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an e-mail with embedded images. Here's what I'm doing...

I have a tinymce text editor where a user can select an image with accompanying text. The e-mail is sent successfully (using CDOSYS - email provider is zohomail) except none of the images are displayed in the e-mail.

Anyone able to tell me what I need to do to display images in an e-mail?

The key function I'm using to convert the image tags to a linked resources is below (uses the agility pack - Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.6.5):

```
public string ConvertToHtmlDocument(string originalText)
    {
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(originalText);

        document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").ToList();

        foreach(var d in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").ToList())
        {
            string base64String = "";
            string currentSrcValue = d.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
            string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Server.MapPath(currentSrcValue));

            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(currentSrcValue)))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                    base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                }
            }

            //currentSrcValue = currentSrcValue.Split(',')[1];//Base64 part of string
            byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            string contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(imageData), mimeType);
            inline.ContentId = contentId;
            inline.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

            d.SetAttributeValue("src", "cid:" + inline.ContentId);
        }

        return document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
```

[[image: Inspect Element]]
[[image: No Image]]

Comment: Can you include the raw content of the email received?

Comment: Edited my post - hope this is what you were looking for.

I notice that the mimetype of the image I used in the email is a png, yet not only is the image not added to the body of the email, but it's included as a gif?

Comment: I was actually looking for the email headers. You may want to tag **Html Agility Pack** on the post. I don't use it, I prefer the old fashioned way

Comment: I'm not opposed to using other methods. Would actually prefer to do without the agility pack. I'm trying to play around with something else as we speak... either way, this sending email with images thing is a new one for me.

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/  This article breaks down the options.  Seems to suggests Outlook doesn't support?